# Delete object from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I know this type of question is asked a lot but my code is different from the other questions (that I've looked at). Below is my code in Swift.

```
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

    context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "StartUp")
    var request3 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request3.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    var results3: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request3, error: nil)!

    res = results [0] as NSManagedObject

    res.setValue(newStart, forKey: "startController")

    if (results3.count > 0) {

        do {

            let user = (results3 as NSArray).lastObject as Users // App crashes here

            context.deleteObject(user)

        } while (results3.count > 0)
    }

    context.save(nil)
```

I'm trying to delete one object from Core Data. The `Users` class is created and has the required NSManagedObject. Why is it crashing?

Comment: What message(s) appear in the console when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing! But I figured it out..I changed "Users" with "NSManagedObject"

Comment: Time to close this question or post/accept your own answer.